# Getting 500 while Download the Google Cloud public signing key:

Tags: kubernetes

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/

As per this documentation,

Download the Google Cloud public signing key:

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
```

when running the above command in ubuntu 22.04, returns 500

[image]

when i try in browser also it is 500.. what is the alternate for this?

https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg

As per this blog, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/961

I have added this

echo `xsBNBGKItdQBCADWmKTNZEYWgXy73FvKFY5fRro4tGNa4Be4TZW3wZpct9Cj8EjykU7S9EPoJ3EdKpxFltHRu7QbDi6LWSNA4XxwnudQrYGxnxx6Ru1KBHFxHhLfWsvFcGMwit/znpxtIt9UzqCm2YTEW5NUnzQ4rXYqVQK2FLG4weYJ5bKwkY+ZsnRJpzxdHGJ0pBiqwkMT8bfQdJymUBown+SeuQ2HEqfjVMsIRe0dweD2PHWeWo9fTXsz1Q5abiGckyOVyoN9//DgSvLUocUcZsrWvYPaN+o8lXTO3GYFGNVsx069rxarkeCjOpiQOWrQmywXISQudcusSgmmgfsRZYW7FDBy5MQrABEBAAHNUVJhcHR1cmUgQXV0b21hdGljIFNpZ25pbmcgS2V5IChjbG91ZC1yYXB0dXJlLXNpZ25pbmcta2V5LTIwMjItMDMtMDctMDhfMDFfMDEucHViKcLAYgQTAQgAFgUCYoi11AkQtT3IDRPt7wUCGwMCGQEAAMGoCAB8QBNIIN3Q2D3aahrfkb6axd55zOwR0tnriuJRoPHoNuorOpCv9aWMMvQACNWkxsvJxEF8OUbzhSYjAR534RDigjTetjK2i2wKLz/kJjZbuF4ZXMynCm40eVm1XZqU63U9XR2RxmXppyNpMqQO9LrzGEnNJuh23icaZY6no12axymxcle/+SCmda8oDAfa0iyA2iyg/eU05buZv54MC6RB13QtS+8vOrKDGr7RYp/VYvQzYWm+ck6DvlaVX6VB51BkLl23SQknyZIJBVPm8ttU65EyrrgG1jLLHFXDUqJ/RpNKq+PCzWiyt4uy3AfXK89RczLu3uxiD0CQI0T31u/IzsBNBGKItdQBCADIMMJdRcg0Phv7+CrZz3xRE8Fbz8AN+YCLigQeH0B9lijxkjAFr+thB0IrOu7ruwNY+mvdP6dAewUur+pJaIjEe+4s8JBEFb4BxJfBBPuEbGSxbi4OPEJuwT53TMJMEs7+gIxCCmwioTggTBp6JzDsT/cdBeyWCusCQwDWpqoYCoUWJLrUQ6dOlI7s6p+iIUNIamtyBCwb4izs27HdEpX8gvO9rEdtcb7399HyO3oD4gHgcuFiuZTpvWHdn9WYwPGM6npJNG7crtLnctTR0cP9KutSPNzpySeAniHx8L9ebdD9tNPCWC+OtOcGRrcBeEznkYh1C4kzdP1ORm5upnknABEBAAHCwF8EGAEIABMFAmKItdQJELU9yA0T7e8FAhsMAABJmAgAhRPk/dFj71bU/UTXrkEkZZzE9JzUgan/ttyRrV6QbFZABByf4pYjBj+yLKw3280//JWurKox2uzEq1hdXPedRHICRuh1Fjd00otaQ+wGF3kY74zlWivB6Wp6tnL9STQ1oVYBUv7HhSHoJ5shELyedxxHxurUgFAD+pbFXIiK8cnAHfXTJMcrmPpC+YWEC/DeqIyEcNPkzRhtRSuERXcq1n+KJvMUAKMD/tezwvujzBaaSWapmdnGmtRjjL7IxUeGamVWOwLQbUr+34MwzdeJdcL8fav5LA8Uk0ulyeXdwiAK8FKQsixI+xZvz7HUs8ln4pZwGw/TpvO9cMkHogtgzQ== | base64 -d > apt-key.gpg`

but still getting the same error

```
changan@Master:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for changan:
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Get:1 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease [8,993 B]
Err:1 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
E: The repository 'https://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/961

Comment: can you execute curl in verbose mode for more detailed response and post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are geeting HTTP code 500 error because of this url https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg

**Below is the workaround**

Run the below command:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/961#issuecomment-1445711531

```
echo 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 | base64 -d | sudo apt-key add -
```

If you specified a `signed-by` path when they added the repo like [this example](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb), they need to modify the workaround specifying the correct keyfile path.

Running the below command will reveal the path,

```
grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep "packages.cloud.google.com/apt"
```

For example, if you specified the path to `/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg`, then need to replace the last part of the workaround pipeline with `sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -`

You can report the issue to google by using the link  [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: There is a  similar public issue tracker raised follow it for more info https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270782614